# Does the modulo operation act in different bases?

Tags: javascript, math, modulo

I'm confused by the properties of the modulo (mod) operator in different bases. Say I'm calculating 230<sub>10</sub> % 11<sub>10</sub> = 10<sub>10</sub>. If I switched to base 16, would E6<sub>16</sub> % B<sub>16</sub> = A<sub>16</sub>? Does the number system's base matter for the mod operation?

(Note: I'm using this for a little calculator app in JavaScript that I'm writing, but I don't see why the language should matter.)

Comment: Base only defines the number representation, operators still keep the same meaning.

Comment: @zerkms is dead on. The base used to represent the number will never impact the value of a mathematical function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The modulo (mod) operator means take the remainder after a division.  The value of that remainder does not depend on base.  The computer uses binary.  Only when you input or display the number does the base matter.

In other words, **base** is all about how a value is displayed.  Consider the number represented by Roman Numeral **X**.  You could also display this as **10** in decimal (base ten), or **1010** in binary.  If you divide by Roman Numeral **IV** (**4** decimal or **0100** binary), you get a remainder of Roman Numeral **II**, or **2** in decimal, or **0010** in binary.

In summary, the *values* in the three equations are the same - only the display changes:

```
X mod IV = II         // Roman Numerals
10 mod 4 = 2          // Base ten (decimal)
1010 mod 0100 = 0010  // Binary
```

For clarity to the user, you will probably want to require that all your operands and the mod result are in the same base.

Comment: Thanks you! That is what I wanted to know. I suspected as much, but I was afraid I was fooling myself by performing the modulo incorrectly. Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

88₍₁₀₎ --> 130₍₈₎ --> 10021₍₃₎

The thing with modulo and bases is that you have to be careful of what you do with
and how you do it...

In you wanted to convert any number with a base other than 10 with this method using modulo it wouldn't work... I'am currently seeking to create modulo for each bases...

[Here's a little table I did to explain my point of view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Z4V.png)